# WKWebView implement javascript remove() but empty lines left

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm using `WKWebview` load a very simple HTML page. The page likes below:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script> p(2099, "AO1");</script>
    <script> p(2099, "AO2");</script>
    <script> p(2099, "AO3");</script>
    <script> p(2099, "AO4");</script>
    <script> p(2099, "AO5");</script>
    <script> p(2099, "AO6");</script>
</body>

</html>
```

And what I'm going to do is remove the first five `script` tags by script language. I added a button for testing.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var tags = document.body.getElementsByTagName('script');
            for (var i = tags.length - 2; i >= 0; --i) {
                tags[i].remove();
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">
        remove</button>
    <script> p(2099, "AO1");</script>
    <script> p(2099, "AO2");</script>
    <script> p(2099, "AO3");</script>
    <script> p(2099, "AO4");</script>
    <script> p(2099, "AO5");</script>
    <script> p(2099, "AO6");</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then when click `remove` button then I can see only the last `script` tag was left. everything works great.

**The html will be kept inserting `<script> p(2099, "AO7");</script>` etc.
I just want to get the last one.**

OK, then I try it in my iOS WkWebView by implement the `myFunction()` js code.

```
let removeScript =
    """
    var tags = document.body.getElementsByTagName('script');
    for (var i = tags.length - 2; i >= 0; --i) {
        tags[i].remove()
    }
    """

self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.innerHTML",
                                            completionHandler: { (html: Any?, error: Error?) in
                  guard error == nil else {
                        return
                  }

                 guard let html = html as? String else {
                    return
                 }
                print("nnnew\(html)nnnew")
                self.webView.evaluateJavaScript(self.removeScript)
}
```

Then the output is:

```
nnnew





<script> p(2099, "AO6");</script>
<script> p(2099, "AO7");</script>
nnnew
```

That is there are many empty lines there. Any way to let the WKWebView remove the empty lines?